# Ways to check for division by zero

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catch a division by zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071067/how-to-catch-a-division-by-zero)

Aside from checking if the denominator is 0, are there other ways to check for a division of zero in php?

Comment: Q: Is there any other way to check for a denominator of "0" besides checking to see if the denominator is zero?  Sure!  Just set the "prescience=true" flag in your php.ini file.  Be sure to restart the server after changing the setting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071067/how-to-catch-a-division-by-zero

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way to check for division by 0 other than checking the denominator isn't 0 before attempting the division.

Why is checking the denominator first a problem? It's only 1 additional line of code.