# PHP Try catch issue

Tags: php, exception

I don't understand why php code dosen't go to catch section?
instead it's showing warning :
Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 3
INF

```
<?php
try{
    echo 5/0;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Divide by 0 not allow.";
}
?>
```

Can anyone help how to manage this?
There is so many question answer regarding this but can't find any perfect solution as c#, Java support try catch handling why php not following same standard?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28281624/6444625 direct answer link

Comment: @Tudor do you know answer why i have to throw manually?

Comment: @NishitManjarawala because a warning and a exception are two different things. By default a warning does not interrupt script execution in terms of throwing anything you could catch. As of PHP 7 there is an an exception thrown (which you could catch) automatically tho (http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php).