# Laravel Throwable not handle exception - get 500 internal error

Tags: php, laravel, exception, http-status-code-500, throwable

In `Laravel` I have the following controller and method:

```
public function uploadattachment(Request $request)    
{
    
    try {
        $aa = 3/0;
    }
    catch (Throwable $t) {
      
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'Error', 
            'message' => $t->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```

[image: 500 internal server error]

When I call above method from Angular I get error `500 internal server error`. I thought that I will receive `200` and exception will be handled in `catch` clause in message property

---

Throwable is under Exception. If dividing by zero is handled by Exception it should be by Throwable as well: [division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071067/php-how-to-catch-a-division-by-zero)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Kenny Horna I wasn't suggesting your answer was wrong BTW, just that the exception is present in PHP 7. Anyway the answer is in the duplicate target.

Comment: @miken32 it's ok. I confirmed that indeed you can catch the exception.